# I've been downvoted for flagging a duplicate

Tags: support

I flagged a question as a possible duplicate and got insulted from the asker. Then he deleted his post and immediately after downvoted two of my recent posts. At least I think so (I'm not privileged to see downvotes in detail). [Click here for more information](https://xkcd.com/2090/)

Since this question is a duplicate it should imo be closed. Thanks to all of you for being so supportive!

Comment: Just for the record: I believe the OP is right that the duplicate doesn't answer their question.

Comment: It was flagged as **possible** duplicate which I thought was peer-reviewed. I didn't mean any offense to the OP. At first glance it seemed the same issue with the exception that OP had a syntax error in it. I would have retracted the flag when OP had pointed me to it not being the same issue. I have already done do before.

Comment: Even if you are convinced that he downvoted you, you have no formal proof. There is a little chance your are wrong. If it's a serial voting it will get corrected by the system, if not I guess you have to simply "move on". Unfortunately, some users don't like when we do some actions against them. So you need to *accept* this as we cannot change the way people behave on the site. You will probably get used to this. Of course, any bad comment should be flagged as we should not accept such thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't already, flag comments like that and *move on*.  You didn't engage them in any further banter so that was at least a positive thing on your part, but in all reality, responses like that don't merit much more than a quick flag for rudeness, and one simply moving past the altercation.

Comment: @digijay you can flag one of your own posts, give a link to the now deleted question if you still have it, and explain what happened. A moderator will look into the history of the commenter and will investigate the votes.

Comment: No, flag that when it happens.  There was a good 12 minutes between when the comment showed up and when the question was deleted.  Doesn't look like you missed much there.

Comment: @digijay yes, there is nothing you could (or even should try) to do after you followed rene's recommendation. If you want something to read to feel better - search for ["revenge downvotes"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=revenge+downvotes) here...

Comment: @digijay It's likely that the OP has already been warned about that known misbehaviour. Other than that, you can take the DV's with pride as scars of battle. :]